# Multiple background worker in chain

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

i have a sequence of 3 time consuming functions, i would like to execute them in background worker or whatever else tool, my problem is that each function should wait for the precedent function to complete, so this is my pseudo-code :

```
open_session() // during the execution of this function i like to display a loading-window 

open_session() //this function opens a process another windows app , while opening this app i would like to keep the current app responsive.

close_session()// during the execution of this function i like to display a loading-window
```

i imagined to do this using background worker, but do function are asynchrounous.

Any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just start each consecutive worker in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler of the previous one...

**Adressing the downvotes:** note that it's a *possibility*. Whether or not it's a good choice, obviously depends on the context, like always. I don't believe in golden rules such as "it's better to just only use one BGW". I can imagine plenty of circumstances, under which using a single BW for all tasks wouldn't simplify matters (for example, if each operation requires `ProgressChanged` to be handled differently).

The OP asked about multiple background workers, not having given enough context to judge what approach is best - for all I know, he could be just theoretically wondering how one can "chain" BWs, in order to gain a better understanding of how BW works.

Comment: Why bother going through the overhead of managing all of those extra threads/tasks if you're just going to synchronize them anyway.  It's better to just only use one BGW in the first place.

Comment: @Servy what type of overhead is it, really? It could potentially make the code more readable, for example if one is using `e.Result`, and the assigned result is of a different type upon completion of each task. I've seen code chucking all the asynchronous stuff into one big `DoWork` event handler; not going through the overhead of managing extra threads perhaps, but bloated and more difficult to debug.

Comment: yeah i'm looking for your solution, but i tried to avoid to play with BGW RunWorkerCompleted  event , there's no way to avoid playing this event ?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use `RunWorkerCompleted`? You could use other threading constructs, leaving `BackgroundWorker` behind (such as `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne`), but it could be an overkill and it's hard to give you advice without knowing what it is that you're trying to achieve and what affects your choices.

Answer (score 10):

Why not execute all three of them sequencially in the same background worker? So, your backgroundworker work event would look like this:

```
private void yourBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    open_session();
    open_session();
    close_session();
}
```

That way, the backgroundworker itself is async, but the three methods that you want to run sequentially are still run sequentially within the context of the async method.